# Developing drag drop swap javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am implementing a drag and drop code, what I have at the moment is 6 dragable and dropable images, what this code does is when an image is dragged over another one they swap also all the images swap places as well (like a sort) what Im tryin to do is only swap positions of the 2 images, leaving the rest alone, any ideas plz??? the code (javascript and jquery) -

```
function itemInSpot(drag_item, spot) {
    var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
    if (oldSpotItem.length > 0) {
        oldSpotItem.appendTo('#inventory').draggable({
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
    }
    var item = $('<img />');
    item.attr('src', drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class', drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    drag_item.remove(); // remove the old object
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circles").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#inventory').droppable();
    $("#circles").droppable({
        accept: '.circles'
    })
    $('#circles,#inventory').bind('drop', function(ev, ui) {
        itemInSpot(ui.draggable, this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your html or even better, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML markup I'm guessing that #circles is a drop zone that contains many images. That is making it harder to find out which image was dropped on. Instead, why not make each image a drop target instead of the entire #circles element? That way you know exactly which image was dropped onto and your swap function is working only with the images themselves and not with an entire element containing lots of images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you provide some code maybe to get me started thanks, or any examples??